# Apache with mod_rewrite in use and FilesMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|png|gif|jpg)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
Header set Expires "A31536000"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I also have a rewrite for `/forum-js/forum.js` -> `/wp-content/plugins/forum/js/forum.js.php`, this is the only file that should match the above regex.  For some reason, all other resources matching that regex have headers that include `Cache-Control` and `Expires`, but this one does not.  Is it because it's a rewritten url?

Comment: What kind of a rewrite do you have for that file? What is its real name?

Comment: `Expires: pA31536000` is invalid; [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) this is not the same as [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because it's a rewritten url?

Yup, as per your comment, its real extension is `.php` and the rules associated with that extension are in effect.

The easiest thing would be to send the headers from within the PHP script:

```
<? header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000");
   header("Expires : pA31536000");
```

Comment: The one problem with this is I cannot actually modify the script - perhaps I should've specified this in the question, but I'm running WordPress, and if this plugin were to be updated the code I add would be overwritten.  The update could be months in the future in which case I would certainly have forgotten where the code goes and what code to add, and in the end it just becomes too complicated and difficult to maintain.  Is there some way I can add these headers with .htaccess?  Should I use <FilesMatch "/wp-content/plugins/forum/js/forum.js.php">?

Comment: @CMC yup, I think a `FilesMatch` is the best option then.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) instead:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|png|gif|jpg)$">
        ExpiresDefault A31536000
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It also works with MIME media types instead of file name extensions:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
</IfModule>
```